# @Value annotation from Spring3 doesn't work in my program

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm writing a java application with Spring 3.It's working well with xml,but not working at all in annotation.

here's my snippet:

```
@Service("oracleDB")
public class OracleDatabase implements IDatabase
{
     @Value("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") 
     private String driverName;
     @Value("jdbc:oracle:thin:@")
     private String url;

     public String getDriverName()
     {
          return driverName;
     }
 }
```

My ApplicationContext.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.pdiwt.database"></context:component-scan>
        </beans>
```

MyInvoker is like that:

```
public class MyInvoker{
   public static void main(String args[]){
        XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
        OracleDatabase oracelDB = beanFactory.getBean("oracleDB");
        System.out.println(oracleDB.getDriverName());
   }
}
```

guess what? The result is null. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: OracleDatabase oracelDB = beanFactory.getBean("oraceDB"); you have already found and corrected this typo error, right? (bean name should be oracleDB)

Comment: Yeah,bean name is oracleDB,I wrote by mistake.The question is why autowiring doesn't work?Does it have anyting to do with beanFactory.getBean()?I know,if I initiate the class by new() manually,the autowiring doesn't work.

Comment: "new" and autowiring are exclusive.  If you call "new", the bean is not under Spring's control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is using xmlbeanfactory, which is a common mistake. Try this instead, it will work perfectly:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
OracleDatabase oracleDB = (OracleDatabase)context.getBean("oracleDB");
...
```

I think the beanfactory is simply not powerful enough to handle the @Value annotations. More information can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Spring, why would you get a connection this way instead of using Spring's DataSources?  Seems odd at best; wrong-headed at worst.

I'd be giving that Repository a JdbcTemplate.

Comment: I'm just giving a simple examle,I'm not gonna use jdbctemplate.The question is why the autowiring doesn't work?

Comment: It works perfectly if you do it right.  I don't see why JdbcTemplate is objectionable.  You don't say what "doesn't work" looks like.  I think the bean factory returns an Object, but I don't see a cast.  Doesn't the compiler flag you for that?

Comment: Let me make it straight,I'm not using jdbc,I'm just giving an example that autowring doesn't work in my case.I'm working on application not web,if it's giving any clue.In the simple case,there's no exception.If to say wiring a bean and trying to invoke a method from that bean,an Nullpointer exception will be throw,cause the DI doesn't work